# Swift: UITextField keyboard return key is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

Below is my code for hiding keyboard on pressing return key, But it's not working.

```
class AddHall: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var hallname: UITextField!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         hallname.delegate = self
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(hallname : UITextField!) -> Bool { 
        hallname.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `view.endEditing(true)`

Comment: textview return key is use to enter next line

Comment: your method name is wrong so you are not getting call. update with this ; 
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement correct UITextField Delegate method.

**replace**

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(hallname : UITextField!) -> Bool { 
    hallname.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

**with**

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn` is used to specify if the text field is allowed to lose the focus - it will only be called just *before*  the UITextField is about to lose its focus. You should only do some checks her, but not dismiss anything.

What you seek is to react on the return key, and then dismiss the keyboard. This is done by connecting the `DidEndOnExit` action (**be aware:** there are a lot of other events with similar names, you'll have to exactly use this one), and there resign the first responder.

[image: DidEndOnExit]

You can then just remove `textFieldShouldReturn` (unless you do some additional checks here and not simply return `true`).

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this. You are not using correct delegate method.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField : UITextField!) -> Bool { 
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct function name for TextField Delegate

Use this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

None of these worked alone for me. Rather:

1. Ensure ViewController extends from both:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

2. Add delegate from TextField to ViewController via Storyboard or programmatically:

```
textField.delegate = self
```

3. Define function in ViewController:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     self.view.endEditing(true)
     textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return false
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to call both `endEditing` and `resignFirstResponder`.